# Don't understand this error: name 'person' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a class named `person`. The error is `name 'person' is not defined`. How can I solve this problem?

```
class person:
    person.count = 0
    def __init__(self,gender,location,DOB):
        # this is constructor method
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__location = location
        self.__DOB = DOB
        # to make the variable inaccessible from out of the class 
        # we have to prefix it with at least two underscores
        print(person.__self)
        print(person.__DOB)
        person.count += 1
    def getname(self):
        #this is access method
        return person.__self
    def getDOB(self):
        return person.__DOB
    def _del_(self):
        print('deleted')
```

Comment: This is actually very simple, though. Just change `person.count = 0` to `count = 0`. It's already in the `person` scope.

Comment: Also, `person.__self` is going to fail, because you never assign `__self`.  Everywhere you want to access the attribute of a specific person, you should be accessing the attribute of the instance, `self`, not the class, `person`.

Comment: Note that `_del_` should be `__del__`, that is a double underscore.  However, as a destructor it is unreliable.

Comment: >>> krishna = person('male','pune','26/05/1996')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    krishna = person('male','pune','26/05/1996')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: i edited as per your instruction but, another error is shown when i try to create an object

Answer (score 1):

First of all, put the line `person.count = 0` inside `__init__`. Next, change every `person` to `self` (unless it's the class definition).

Comment: also `__self` is not defined anywhere. You might want to define it in `__init__

Comment: I think `count` is deliberately a class variable, not an instance variable. It appears to be a way to track the number of instances created. Adding it to `__init__()` will cause it to reset every time an instance is created.